# Is the orbit foliation of the Weyl chamber flow Riemannian?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, group-actions, foliations

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$Fix an integer $p\geq 1$ and a cocompact lattice $\Gamma\subset \SL(p+1,\mathbb{R})$. Consider the manifold
$$
M_{\Gamma}:=\SL(p+1,\mathbb{R})/\Gamma.
$$
Let $A\subset \SL(p+1,\mathbb{R})$ be the subgroup of diagonal matrices with positive entries. The action
$$
A\curvearrowright M_{\Gamma};\  a\cdot x\Gamma=(ax)\Gamma
$$
is called the **Weyl chamber flow**. Denote by $\mathcal{F}$ the orbit foliation on $M_{\Gamma}$.
Is  $\mathcal{F}$ Riemannian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These foliations are very far from being Riemannian.

Consider the case $p=1$, and take $PSL(2,\mathbb R)$ instead of $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ (just to simplify a bit). I'll explain how to construct an example where one non-compact leaf converges to a compact one (a circle). Such behavior implies that the foliation is not Riemannian.

Let $\Gamma_g\subset PSL(2,\mathbb R)$ be the fundamental group of a genus $g\ge 2$ surface. You can think of $PSL(2,\mathbb R)$ the unit tangent bundle to $\mathbb H^2$ (the hyperbolic plane). In fact $SO(2)\setminus PSL(2,\mathbb R)$ can be identified with $\mathbb H^2$. Then $\mathbb H^2/\Gamma_g$ is a compact hyperbolic surface $S_g$. The action of the diagonal group on $PSL(2,\mathbb R)/\Gamma_g$ is the geodesic flow on the unit tangent bundle of $S_g$. Now, this flow has closed orbits - corresponding to closed geodesic on $S_g$. Take such a closed geodesic $\gamma$, then it's not hard to construct a different geodesic that converges to $\gamma$. To see how this looks like, consider, for example Fig 3, in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.07409.pdf .